# Text Recognition and Matching in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get excel to search through a list (column A) and list out the matches in column B. Then count how many times the item appears in column A as well. Example: I have a list of people input their favorite foods in column A. Ideally, I would like excel to recognize when an entry is new (not a duplicate) and list it in column B. So if Pizza was typed into Column A, then it would automatically list it in Column B and then the next time it was listed, it would just add it to the count. The count could be in Column C, that doesn't matter. I understand that I can use the "CountIfs" function, but then I would have to list all the foods and update it every time someone listed a food that wasn't already on the list.

Looking for a way around this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding this clearly but why not input what you want in column B into a separate sheet and run a macro for column B by reading the content from sheet 2?